# Localization en blazor web assembly (data annotation)

Tags: c#, validación, blazor, localización, annotation

Blazor Web Assembly net 6. Tengo en el proyecto client el localization, y los archivos resx tambien el ese proyecto. El tema es que los modelos de las clases esta en el proyecto Shared (biblioteca de clases). Estas clases tienen las propiedades con los Data Annotation definido pero no logro poder traducir los mensajes de validacion en los formularios del proyecto client. Si puedo, declarar un nuevo objeto en el razor del proyecto client con los data annotation y los traduce perfecto, pero no puedo con los mensajes del proyecto Shared ya que el Shared no tiene acceso al client.
Este codigo lo tengo en el client y va perfecto con el Editform y el ValidationMessage. Pero al querer poner esto en los modelos del Shared no me reconoce el "Translates" porque esta declarado en el Client, que no tengo acceso.

```
 [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Translates.RequiredField), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Translates))]
 [Display(Name = "Title", ResourceType = typeof(Translates))]
 public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

Se me ocurre poner el localization en el Shared ya que desde el client tengo acceso al Shared, o sino crear una referencia inversa, o sea, que el shared tenga como referecnia al client, pero no me gusta mucho esta opcion.